# How to autowire a class which is in another project

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two java projects as epService and epEntity (factory classes for db access). And there is another Spring project as epWeb which contains controllers and this is a Rest API.
Now, I want to autowire a class which is inside epEntity to the spring project epWeb.
I have successfully autowired classes within that epWeb project but I was unable to autowire a class from another project
Anyone have a suggestion for doing that, please let me know.
If this is an irrelevant question for stackoverflow, please delete this.

The class where I autowire
public class Mapper {

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
@Autowired
private AppointmentFactory af;
@Autowired
private AppointmentController ac;
}
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mobios.ep.web.controllers" />
    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.mobios.ep.services" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ombios.ep.entity.factory" /> -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>      
    </bean> 
     <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
     <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1048576"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: You can autowire beans that live inside the same spring application context. If two projects are being deployed independently, each one has its own application context and thus, there is no way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. epWeb project has dependencies on both epService  and epEntity. So, I deployed only epWeb. That means epWeb (Spring) project code can access classes inside epEntity

Comment: Ok, then you can use `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"...package...."})` of the related packages containing Controllers etc. or if there are not many, you can probably declare them as Beans in a `@Configuration` class.

Comment: I tried with adding @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"...package...."}) to a class which inside epService but It still not working. It gives me below error.      Error creating bean with name 'appointmentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'iService': No qualifying bean of type etc

Comment: Did you make sure the package where `iService` (the implementation) lives? You have to add this to `@ComponentScan` too. `@ComponentScan({"com.example.service","com.example.controller"})`

Comment: Yes, iService which is type of AppointmentService resides under the com.mobios.ep.services package

Comment: And I assume `iService` is annotated with `@Service`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works.  Earlier @Service annotation was missing, that is why it was not working.

Comment: Glad to here. Do you mind if I post an answer to the question in order for you to vote up and accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `@ComponentScan` annotation in your main application `epWeb` in order to register in Spring context classes which live in `epEntity` project as Beans (Controllers, Services etc).

```
@ComponentScan({"com.example.service", "com.example.controlle‌​r"})
```

Also, make sure that Service implementations are annotated with `@Service` in `epEntity` project.

Answer (score 0):

My sugestion is to create an spring-config.xml file in both projects for own spring beans configurations (you used the name mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml) and on web.xml to map both files for contextConfigLocation, so both projects will be in same spring context.

Also you can use a specified pattern for spring config files and to use a regex for contextConfigLocation.

web.xml fragment:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
        classpath:view-spring-config.xml
        classpath:service-spring-config.xml
      </param-value>
  </context-param>
```

or

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
        classpath:*-spring-config.xml
      </param-value>
  </context-param>
```