# spring not able to autowire beans in another project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am facing same issue as mentioned in [how-to-autowire-a-class-which-is-in-another-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667258/how-to-autowire-a-class-which-is-in-another-project). Given solution didn't worked for me. I've already added

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sharma.nks.ht"/>
```

I can find the beans are getting created by spring container. I've use same bean in another project so I've imported another projects application context :

```
    <import resource="classpath*:spring/bussvc-application-config.xml" />
```

Still Spring is not able to find beans.
What is happening in this scenario? Is spring creating another container...? Does it mean spring can have more than 1 container?
Can any one please help here.

Comment: That bean is null in your application?

Comment: With these information , unable to tell the cause. Add more code

Comment: soc-tution-bussvc
-com.sharma.nks.ht.svc.ExBean.java
{ public ExBean() {
  System.out.println("ExBean created!");
 }
}
-bussvc-application-config.xml
    <bean class="com.sharma.nks.ht.daos.ExBean" id="exBean" />

------------------------------------------------------
soc-tution-channel
-com.sharma.nks.ht.WelcomeController.java
@Autowired ExBean exBean;




------------------------------------------------------
Console log:
ExBean created!